# Recursion - returning a new number with bigger digits than the parameter

Tags: java, recursion

I have an exercise in which I have to write a recursive method that receives an integer and a digit d. This method has to return a new number, consisting only digits which is bigger than d.

for example, for the number 19473, and the digit 3, the returned number will be 947.

So far I haven't gotten some progress in my code, so I don't have anything to show you.
The method's signature:

```
public static int filter(int n, int d)
```

Any help would be great,

Thank you.

Comment: anything you tried to get the desired result?

Comment: so far I have gotten..nothing :(

Comment: So you will get nothing from here without trying :p

Comment: Convert the number to a string - this will make it easier to determine the individual digits

Comment: well this might be a good idea - seperate each digit and than add them to a String and convert at the end to int - but isn't that "cheating"? I don't really return a number...

Comment: Unless the assignment says "don't use strings" then I doubt that it's cheating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer in great details:

```
int filter(int n, int d) {
    if (n >= 0 && d >= 0) {    // n and d non-negetive

        if (n == 0) {   // terminating criteria
            return 0;
        } else {
            int currDigit = n % 10;
            if (n % 10 > d) {
                return filter(n / 10, d) * 10 + currDigit; //gathering digits greater thand d
            } else {
                return filter(n / 10, d);  // ignoring digits less than or equal d
            }
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

One thing you should know, If you are new in coding and want to be a great coder! My advice to you is, don't take away the opportunities from your brain to think about the coding problems! Always trust your brain. Keep patient. Try and try again.

Cheers and Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

```
public static int filter(int n, int d)
{
   if (n==0) return 0;
   if (n%10>d) return 10*filter(n/10,d)+n%10;
   else return filter(n/10,d);
}
```

The key to understand:

A integer n(n>10), assume a=n/10 b=n%10.

You can see filter(n)=(String)filter(a)+(String)filter(b) (I mean,convert the result to string and concatenate the two strings. It's not valid in syntax, it's just for understanding it).

But we don't need to get hands dirty with String, arithmetics will do the same job for integers.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not recursive.

Comment: An explanation of the thought process that led to this code would make for a better answer, particularly as OP is doing this as an exercise.